# intitializing an ArrayList attribute to the parameter List<t> inside the constructor

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having problems with initializing an attribute called list which is an ArrayList

```
public class SensorList<T extends Sensor> {

ArrayList<T> list;

public SensorList() {
    list = new ArrayList<T>();
}

public SensorList(List<T> t) {
    list = this.list
}

public void add(T t) {
    list.add(t);
}

public void remove(T t) {
    list.remove(t);
}
```

every time I do this step it gives me an error stating that ArrayList cannot be converted to List So how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

All `ArrayList`s implement the `List` interface but not all `List` implementations are `ArrayList`s. Therefore you can assign an `ArrayList` instance to a `List` variable, but not vice versa.

Either change

```
ArrayList<T> list;
```

to

```
List<T> list;
```

or change

```
public SensorList(List<T> t)
```

to

```
public SensorList(ArrayList<T> t)
```

A third option is to convert the passed `List` to an `ArrayList`:

```
public SensorList(List<T> t) {
    this.list = new ArrayList<T>(t);
}
```

The former is usually the preferred option, since it allows your class to work with any `List` implementation.

P.S.

I'm assuming

```
list = this.list
```

is a typo and you meant

```
this.list = t;
```

Comment: but the questions said that I need to initialize the ArrayList to the parameter in the constructor List<T> so How?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `ArrayList<T>` to `List<T>`, but you cannot assign `List<T>` to `ArrayList<T>` (think of it, it could actually be another type of `List<T>`, such as `LinkedList<T>`).

It is usually a good idea to user the less specific types that you are able to use. In your case, it is enough if `list` has type `List<T>`, and your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

The **proper** way of handling this:

- change the type of your field to be `List<T>`, not ArrayList
- change your first constructor body to a simple `this(new ArrayList<>());`

The point is: you really *only* want to use the implementation specific type ArrayList when creating new lists. All the other time, prefer to only use the *interface* type List.

Beyond that: list is a bad name. It doesn't say anything about the purpose of that variable. You could simply call it `sensors` for example to express A) the plural B) the things that this list will be dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your constructor to this. You don't want to set the list parameter, but rather **your** list field. So you should change it like so:

```
public SensorList(List<T> t) {
    this.list = (ArrayList)t;
}
```

or change it into this:

```
public SensorList(ArrayList<T> list){
    this.list = list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong declaration for `LIST`. Always have `Generic Declaration` and after that assign it's implementation.

```
List<T> list;

public SensorList() {
    list = new ArrayList<T>();
}

public SensorList(List<T> t) {
    list = this.list
}

public void add(T t) {
    list.add(t);
}

public void remove(T t) {
    list.remove(t);
}`
```